# Buttons in React component not responding to clicks: the buttons are like the text only

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working on a React project, and I have a component that displays a shopping cart. In this cart, I have buttons for adding and removing items, but I'm experiencing an issue where the buttons are not responding to clicks as expected.

I have a Cart component that renders the cart items, and I'm using buttons for adding and removing items from the cart. When I click these buttons, nothing happens. They don't trigger the intended actions.

```
    import React from "react";

const Cart = ({ cartElements, updateCart }) => {
  const subtotal = cartElements.reduce(
    (acc, element) => acc + element.price * element.quantity,
    0
  );
  const shipping = subtotal < 500 ? 40 : 0;
  const total = subtotal + shipping;

  // Function to remove an item from the cart
  const removeFromCart = (index) => {
    console.log("remove");
    // Use the confirm dialog to ask for confirmation
    const shouldRemove = window.confirm(
      "Are you sure you want to remove this item from the cart?"
    );

    if (shouldRemove) {
      // Create a new array without the item to remove
      const updatedCart = cartElements.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
      updateCart(updatedCart);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100 h-screen py-8">
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Shopping Cart</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-4">
          <div className="md:w-3/4">
            <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-6 mb-4">
              <table className="w-full">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th className="text-left font-semibold">Product</th>
                    <th className="text-left font-semibold">Price</th>
                    <th className="text-left font-semibold">Quantity</th>
                    <th className="text-left font-semibold">Total</th>
                    <th className="text-left font-semibold">Remove</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {cartElements.map((element, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td className="py-4">
                        <div className="flex items-center">
                          <img
                            src={element.imageUrl}
                            alt="Product Image"
                            className="h-16 w-16 mr-4"
                          />
                          <span className="font-semibold">{element.title}</span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td className="py-4">₹{element.price}</td>
                      <td className="py-4">
                        <div className="flex items-center">
                          <button>test</button>
                          <button
                            className="border rounded-md py-2 px-4 mr-2"
                            onClick={() => removeFromCart(index)}
                          >
                            -
                          </button>
                          <span className="text-center w-8">
                            {element.quantity}
                          </span>
                          <button
                            className="border rounded-md py-2 px-4 ml-2"
                            onClick={() => removeFromCart(index)}
                          >
                            +
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td className="py-4">
                        ₹{(element.price * element.quantity).toFixed(2)}
                      </td>
                      <td className="py-4">
                        <button
                          className="text-red-500 bg-transparent hover:bg-red-500 hover:text-white"
                          onClick={() => removeFromCart(index)}
                        >
                          Remove
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Summary Section */}
          <div className="md:w-1/4">
            <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-6">
              <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold mb-4">Summary</h2>

              {/* Subtotal */}
              <div className="flex justify-between mb-2">
                <span>Subtotal</span>
                <span>₹{subtotal.toFixed(2)}</span>
              </div>

              {/* Shipping - You can replace this with actual calculation */}
              <div className="flex justify-between mb-2">
                <span>Shipping</span>
                <span>₹{shipping.toFixed(2)}</span>
              </div>

              {/* Total */}
              <hr className="my-2" />
              <div className="flex justify-between mb-2">
                <span className="font-semibold">Total</span>
                <span className="font-semibold">₹{total.toFixed(2)}</span>
              </div>

              {/* Checkout Button */}
              <button className="bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg mt-4 w-full">
                Checkout
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

and

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cart from "./Cart";

const Header = () => {
  const [isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen] = useState(false);

  const [cartElements, setCartElements] = useState([
    {
      title: "Colors",
      price: 100,
      imageUrl:
        "https://prasadyash2411.github.io/ecom-website/img/Album%201.png",
      quantity: 2,
    },
    {
      title: "Black and white Colors",
      price: 50,
      imageUrl:
        "https://prasadyash2411.github.io/ecom-website/img/Album%202.png",
      quantity: 3,
    },
    {
      title: "Yellow and Black Colors",
      price: 70,
      imageUrl:
        "https://prasadyash2411.github.io/ecom-website/img/Album%203.png",
      quantity: 1,
    },
    // ... Add more cart items as needed
  ]);

  const toggleCart = () => {
    setIsCartOpen(!isCartOpen);
  };

  const updateCart = (newCart) => {
    setCartElements(newCart);
  };

  return (
    <header className="text-gray-600 body-font">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
        <a className="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            className="w-10 h-10 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            <path d="M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5"></path>
          </svg>
          <span className="ml-3 text-xl">The Generics</span>
        </a>
        <nav className="md:ml-auto md:mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
          <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Home</a>
          <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Store</a>
          <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">About</a>
        </nav>
        <button
          onClick={toggleCart}
          className="inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0"
        >
          {/* Display the number of items in the cart */}
          Cart ({cartElements.length}){" "}
          <svg
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            className="w-4 h-4 ml-1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      {isCartOpen && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-50 z-50">
          <button onClick={toggleCart} className="absolute top-0 right-0 p-4">
            X
          </button>
          <div className="pointer-events-none">
            <Cart
              cartElements={cartElements}
              updateCart={updateCart}
              className="pointer-events-auto"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I've tried various solutions, but the buttons still don't work as expected. What could be causing this issue? Are there any common pitfalls when it comes to buttons in React components that I might be missing?

I appreciate any help or guidance on how to make these buttons work as intended.

Additional Information:

I'm using React.
The buttons are not responding to clicks.
I'm using the tailwind framework.

Thank you

Comment: Which action doesn't work? the button to remove item to card or the button to add item to the card? What is the output in your browser console?

Comment: remove item, add item both not working and buttons are not "spawning" as the button for my code they are like the plane text only.

Comment: Add screenshot so we can see how it look